# No such file or directory when using ubuntu python subprocess popen

Tags: python-3.x

So I am running this code to run a python file called FileWriterServer.py, the fullpath in ubuntu after dragging and dropping the file is fullpath

```
import subprocess
import time, threading
import datetime

fullpath = "/home/andersson/Experiment1/public/EkiIn/FileWriterServer.py"

def startServer():
    print("Starting FileWriterServer.py on 8001 at",datetime.datetime.now())
    proc = subprocess.Popen("python3 "+fullpath,shell=False)
    threading.Timer(30,stoppServer,[proc]).start()

startServer()
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for / about?

Comment: how can I make the system Popen command find and run the FileWriterServer.py file

Answer (score 0):

- changed one row to

  proc = subprocess.Popen(["python3",fullpath],shell=False)

Now it works!